# Jquery On Click table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm trying to create a table that had three columns. One with text, and the other two columns one is for a current score, and ideal score. Right now when I try to select a current score and a ideal score separately I can't as I'm only forced to click one. Also the goal is to have the current score display in the current score input once chosen and the ideal score to display in the ideal score input once chosen. But right now the one number that I can click on appears on both inputs. I know there is something wrong with the jquery I can't figure out what is is. What is my jquery is preventing me from getting the functionality I'm trying to achieve???????

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", function(event) {
    clickedHTML = event.target.innerHTML;
    if ($.isNumeric(clickedHTML)) {
      number = clickedHTML;
      $("#gform_7 input.small:visible").val(number);
      $("#current").removeClass("scorecard-clicked");
      event.target.classList.add("scorecard-clicked");
    }
  })
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", function(event) {
    clickedHTML = event.target.innerHTML;
    if ($.isNumeric(clickedHTML)) {
      number = clickedHTML;
      $("#gform_7 input.medium:visible").val(number);
      $("#ideal").removeClass("scorecard-clicked");
      event.target.classList.add("scorecard-clicked");
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="whiteBG">You do not have a well-thought out investment plan.  There is no specific plan to measure allocation, risk and performance.</td>
    <td class="dkgray" id="current"><table >
        <tr>
          <td><p>1</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p>2</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p>3</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
<td class="dkgray" id="ideal"><table>
        <tr>
          <td><p>1</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p>2</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p>3</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  <tr>
    <td class="whiteBG">You have one or several advisors who manage your investments and have a process of tracking all together but there is no strategic plan.</td>
    <td class="ltgray" id="current"><table>
        <tr>
          <td><p>4</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p>5</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p>6</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
<td class="ltgray" id="ideal"><table>
        <tr>
          <td><p>4</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p>5</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p>6</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="whiteBG">You have one or more trusted advisors who coordinate investments but do not have an investment policy statement, coordinated rebalancing or alternative asset oversight and coordination.</td>
    <td class="gold" id="current"><table>
        <tr>
          <td><p>7</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p>8</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p>9</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  <td class="gold" id="ideal"><table>
        <tr>
          <td><p>7</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p>8</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p>9</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="whiteBG">You have one trusted advisor (not necessarily your only investment advisor) with complete oversight of your investment policy statement, asset allocation plan, alternative asset class oversight and allocation/ rebalancing oversight.</td>
    <td class="ltgold" id="current"><table>
        <tr>
          <td><p>10</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
<td class="ltgold" id="ideal"><table>
        <tr>
          <td><p>10</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<label class="gfield_label" for="input_7_2">ENTER CURRENT SCORE<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
<div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text"><input name="input_2" id="input_7_2" type="text" value="" class="small" aria-describedby="gfield_description_7_2" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></div>

<label class="gfield_label" for="input_7_70">ENTER IDEAL SCORE<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
<div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text"><input name="input_70" id="input_7_70" type="text" value="" class="medium" aria-describedby="gfield_description_7_70" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></div>
```

Comment: You haven't really asked a ***specific*** question. Please edit your question and narrow the focus to a specific question about your code, rather than what functionality you'd like to have.

Comment: I did ask a question. I know there is something wrong in the jquery I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: *What is my jquery is preventing me from getting the functionality I'm trying to achieve???????* is not the kind of focused and specific question we generally answer here. Have you looked at your developer's console for errors? What part of the code (exactly) isn't working? Have you verified that that portion of the code is being reached?

Comment: I don't really know what I'm doing I'm really new to jqeury  I don't even know how to get it more specific? Also there aren't any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give classes to the different elements, and delegate the event handlers to those classes.

Note that you shouldn't repeat the same ID in each row of the table, they should be unique. You should use classes instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".current", function(event) {
    var number = $(this).text();
    $("#input_7_2").val(number);
    $("#current").removeClass("scorecard-clicked");
    $(this).addClass("scorecard-clicked");
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".ideal", function(event) {
    var number = $(this).text();
    $("#input_7_70").val(number);
    $("#ideal").removeClass("scorecard-clicked");
    $(this).addClass("scorecard-clicked");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="whiteBG">You do not have a well-thought out investment plan.  There is no specific plan to measure allocation, risk and performance.</td>
    <td class="dkgray" id="current"><table >
        <tr>
          <td><p class="current">1</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="current">2</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="current">3</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
<td class="dkgray" id="ideal"><table>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="ideal">1</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="ideal">2</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="ideal">3</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  <tr>
    <td class="whiteBG">You have one or several advisors who manage your investments and have a process of tracking all together but there is no strategic plan.</td>
    <td class="ltgray" id="current"><table>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="current">4</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="current">5</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="current">6</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
<td class="ltgray" id="ideal"><table>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="ideal">4</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="ideal">5</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="ideal">6</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="whiteBG">You have one or more trusted advisors who coordinate investments but do not have an investment policy statement, coordinated rebalancing or alternative asset oversight and coordination.</td>
    <td class="gold" id="current"><table>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="current">7</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="current">8</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="current">9</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  <td class="gold" id="ideal"><table>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="ideal">7</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="ideal">8</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="ideal">9</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="whiteBG">You have one trusted advisor (not necessarily your only investment advisor) with complete oversight of your investment policy statement, asset allocation plan, alternative asset class oversight and allocation/ rebalancing oversight.</td>
    <td class="ltgold" id="current"><table>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="current">10</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
<td class="ltgold" id="ideal"><table>
        <tr>
          <td><p class="ideal">10</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<label class="gfield_label" for="input_7_2">ENTER CURRENT SCORE<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
<div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text"><input name="input_2" id="input_7_2" type="text" value="" class="small" aria-describedby="gfield_description_7_2" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></div>

<label class="gfield_label" for="input_7_70">ENTER IDEAL SCORE<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
<div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text"><input name="input_70" id="input_7_70" type="text" value="" class="medium" aria-describedby="gfield_description_7_70" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></div>
```

Comment: THank you so much this really helped.